# Copy semantics and vectors

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy, assignment-operator

I am dealing with objects that allocate memory for internal use. Currently, they are not copyable.

E.g.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { Store = new int; }
    ~MyClass() { delete Store; }

private:
    int* Store;
};
```

I would like to add what it takes to allow assignment, both with copy and move semantics, and also be able to store them in vectors (with move semantics). I don't want to use smart pointers, and want to keep it simple.

What class members should I define ? How can I force copy assignment or move assignment ? Which copy will be performed when passing the objects by value or by reference ? Will the implementation differ across the successive versions of C++ ?

E.g.

```
MyClass A, B;
A = B; // How to force copy or move ?
std::vector<MyClass> V = { A, B };
```

Comment: Watch this video from CppCon 2019. Arthur O'Dwyer solves this exact problem when he writes a not-so-naive roll-your-own vector class. [Back to Basics: RAII and the Rule of Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ)

Comment: In summary: You need the five "special" member functions: 1. copy ctor, 2. move ctor, 3. copy assignment operator, 4. move assignment operator, 5. dtor. O'Dwyer recommends also that you write a noexcept `swap` function. He uses the "copy-and-swap" idiom, and shows a way to combine both assignment operators into one function.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use smart pointers? They make your life a lot easier without introducing overhead.

Comment: Regarding O'Dwyer: Here is a link that goes to his [finished functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ&t=2458s). Call it a "cheat sheet". The very next section of the video shows how to do the same thing with `unique_ptr` (and perhaps less work).

Comment: @chrysante: to tell you the whole story, the code is legacy that does not use `stl` at all and I'd like it to remain so. (There is no contradiction to using `std::vector`, this is done outside the code.)

Comment: @tbxfreeware: thank you, a quite interesting presentation. I still need to digest it :-) but presumably I'll got for the rule of 4½.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Hope it helps! O'Dwyer's best talks are of the nut-and-bolts variety. Many are excellent.

Comment: A RAII `unique_ptr` (unlike a `shared_ptr`) is simple to write by yourself, even for use only with your `MyClass` and would separate all those concerns for memory administrative member functions. Together they would not take much more lines than putting all this in `MyClass`.

Comment: @Sebastian: that's an interesting approach, thanks. Leads to the Rule of Zero in the video.

Comment: @Sebastian Indeed, but then the question would have still been asked for this custom `unique_ptr` class since it's  about what members are to be defined :)

Comment: @Fareanor Sure, the question is valid. So are the answers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, if you use smart pointers, they'll already handle everything for you, hence the rule of zero. But if you can't use them and have to create your own smart pointer class, it's like deferring all the work into it (which could be worth the effort if you are to reuse it multiple times)

Comment: @Sebastian But your suggestion was very relevant, especially if OP's is going to reuse the same thing several times.

Comment: For this particular class, change `int *Store` to `int Store` and define no special member functions.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I suspect it was just an example (in OP's real code, it's probably way bigger than a bare `int`)

Comment: It was uneasy to select the accepted answer. Thanks to all. The O'Dwyer video was quite useful. I hope I can investigate Sebastian's suggestion.

Comment: @Fareanor: indeed, the code counts in dozen thousand lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked about vectors, so... here is class `tbx::Vector`. I wrote it as an exercise. Its design follows the talk given by **Arthur O'Dwyer** at CppCon 2019. See the YouTube video entitled [Back to Basics: RAII and the Rule of Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ).

To focus more closely on the copy semantics you ask about, I have included just the five "special" member functions, plus a couple of other ctors and the member functions `reserve` and `swap`. Although class `Vector` implements almost all of the interface of `std::vector`, the other functions do not appear here.

I've left hooks where you can insert whatever code is needed in the event that an allocation attempted by operator `new` fails.

This is not intended as production code. First, why reinvent the wheel? Second, there are many optimizations that have been omitted, Third, some functionality has been omitted, for example, I did not provide the full complement of ctors or support for allocators.

```cpp
template< typename T >
class Vector
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using iterator = value_type*;
    using const_iterator = value_type const*;

private:
    value_type* data_{ nullptr };
    size_type capacity_{};
    size_type size_{};
    enum : size_type { zero, one };

public:
    Vector() noexcept
        = default;

    explicit Vector(size_type const size)
        : data_{ nullptr }, capacity_{ size }, size_{ size }
    {
        if (zero < size)
        {
            try { data_ = new value_type[size]; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { throw; }
        }
    }

    Vector (Vector const& that)
        : data_{ nullptr }
        , capacity_{ that.size_ }  // "shrink to fit"
        , size_{ that.size_ }
    {
        if (that.size_ != zero)
        {
            try { data_ = new value_type[that.size_]; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { throw; }
            std::copy(that.data_, that.data_ + size_, data_);
        }
    }

    Vector (Vector&& that) noexcept
        : data_     { std::exchange(that.data_, nullptr)  }
        , capacity_ { std::exchange(that.capacity_, zero) }
        , size_     { std::exchange(that.size_, zero)     }
    {}

    ~Vector() {
        delete[] data_;
    }

    Vector& operator=(Vector that) noexcept {
        swap(that);
        return *this;
    }

    void reserve(size_type const capacity) {
        if (capacity_ < capacity) {
            value_type* p{ nullptr };
            try { p = new value_type[capacity]; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { throw; }
            if (data_ != nullptr)
                std::copy(data_, data_ + size_, p);
            capacity_ = capacity;
            std::swap(data_, p);
            delete[] p;
        }
    }

    void swap(Vector& that) noexcept {
        using std::swap;
        swap(capacity_, that.capacity_);
        swap(size_, that.size_);
        swap(data_, that.data_);
    }

    friend void swap(Vector& a, Vector& b) noexcept {
        a.swap(b);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"What class members should I define ?"*

You'll need to follow the **rule of five**, which requires to define:

- Destructor
- Copy constructor
- Move constructor
- Copy-assignment operator
- Move-assignment operator

With using smart pointers, you could probably `default` these functions and it would be basically that. This would be the more concise solution.

But since you don't want to use smart pointers, you'll need to do all the shenanigans yourself the good old way.

> *"How can I force copy assignment or move assignment ?"*

```
a = b;            // copy-assignment
a = std::move(b); // move-assignment
```

`std::move()` will basically `static_cast` the argument to a r-value reference so that the proper operator overload (move-assignment) will be called.

> *"Which copy will be performed when passing the objects by value or by reference ?"*

When passing by value, a copy will be made. If you want to move instead, you'll need to use `std::move()` again.

When passing by reference, no copy nor move are made. You can think of it as if you passed a pointer to the object (except that the reference is not nullable).

> *"Will the implementation differ across the successive versions of C++ ?"*

Well, who knows the future ? But it should not. Usually they tend to keep backward-compatibility as much as possible in order to avoid breaking old code. But it happens sometimes (for example [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) was such a revolution that breaking some things could not be avoided, but it was necessary).

Anyway, I seriously doubt that the rule of five would become something wrong in future versions :)

---

A possible implementation (example):

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        int * store;

    public:
        //Default constructor
        Foo() : store{nullptr}
        {}

        // Destructor
        ~Foo()
        {
            delete store;
        }

        // Copy constructor
        Foo(const Foo & f) : store{f.store ? new int{*f.store} : nullptr}
        {}
        // Move constructor
        Foo(Foo && f) noexcept : store{std::exchange(f.store, nullptr)}
        {}

        // Copy-assignment operator
        Foo & operator=(const Foo & f)
        {
            if(!f.store)
            {
                delete store;
                store = nullptr;
                return *this;
            }

            if(!store)
                store = new int{};
                
            *store = *f.store;
            return *this;
        }
        // Move-assignment operator
        Foo & operator=(Foo && f) noexcept
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(store, f.store);
            return *this;
        }
};
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/1h7xq5v9Y)</kbd>

Comment: Implementing own swap and utilizing copy-swap idiom somewhat simplifies the code (at the price of always allocating sth in copy assignments).

Comment: @alagner Good point ! However, the code shown was only an illustration of the answer (an example), not the answer itself (Hence why I separated it from the answer with a line). And it is not that complicated though :) But thanks for the notice !

Comment: If I am right, in the copy-assignment operator, reallocation is optional ?

Comment: The copy-assignment should just be `*store = *f.store;`

Comment: The move-construct and move-assign are incorrect as they leave the source in an invalid state (`store` should never be null as evinced by the copy- constructor design)

Comment: Your copy constructor and copy assignment operator might dereference a null pointer. Managing resources like this is hard, you should always use STL containers and smart pointers instead.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili You're right, I neglected the example... I corrected that. And I agree with you, but OP's requirement was to not use standard library containers/smart pointers.

Comment: @M.M It's corrected (see the comment above) Thanks for pointing that out. I've written the example way too fast :/

Comment: @YvesDaoust The `if` statement is to prevent self-assignment. It's not an issue in the general case, but it would be here because you can't copy from something you just deleted right before. And moreover, self-assignment is pointless.

Comment: I am not commenting about the if (I know why). I am commenting about the delete/new sequence (now changed). But I realized that delete/new is not a no-op in case the pointer is initially zero.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh alright. Anyway, I just simplified the example. No deallocation, no `nullptr` handling.

Comment: No, this is not correct, the move constructor should never allocate and it should never fail - yours will fail if the allocation fails. Note that if the move constructor is not noexcept, vector will not use it (see `move_if_noexcept`). Your previous strategy of setting it to null was perfectly correct, you just have to be careful to never derefence that null pointer elsewhere. https://godbolt.org/z/a6e5enbGP

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: this is indeed a pitfall: after a move, a `MyClass` becomes unusable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust After a move the object is supposed to be in a "valid but unspecified" state. So, after moving, the user should be able to set a new value or destroy the old object. Allocating in the move constructor / move assignment operator is not a good idea and it's certainly not what most users expect. You might as well not implement the move constructor at that point.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I rolled back then, I missed the `noexcept` requirement, which makes sense. If it's still wrong, I grant you the right to just remove the example from my answer (the example was not the point of the answer).

Comment: @Fareanor the example looks good to me now (maybe add a constructor that takes an `int` just so there's a way to get a non-empty object. Not crucial for this example). If nothing else, this discussion here shows how difficult it can be to get all of these right and most people should use STL containers most of the time instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you're managing is of fixed size, you can put that directly in the class itself:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
    Data data;
};
```

If the data you're managing is of varying size, you may use a vector:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
};
```

No simpler could it get.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Currently, changing the code to use `stl` containers internally is not an option.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is that because you don't have access to the standard library? If you have constraints, please let us know in the question itself.

Comment: The constraint is portability from C++03 on, and modifying the legacy code as little as possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But before C++11, there was no move semantics...

Comment: @Fareanor: that's the reason of my last question. Does that mean that a C++03 vector cannot avoid deep copies ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, a C++03 vector will copy all the objects when it expands. You can call `reserve` to pre-allocate the buffer to minimize the copies. But C++03 is 20 years old at this point. Most projects have moved on to use C++11 or better.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: my users are quite conservative and some might still use VS2008. But I agree that this tends to vanish.